# Open Source Semantic Search Engines

Tags: python, search-engine

Please suggest me an open source semantic search engine for content enhancement in order to perform a search, rather than just keywords. 
I am currently working in Django (python).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have already found what you were looking for but [Open Semantic Search](https://www.opensemanticsearch.org/) is probably what you're looking for.